# how to check google sing in token is expired or not

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-signin

I'm facing an issue with the expiration of Google Sign-In tokens in my React Native app. Despite my attempts to resolve it, I haven't been successful. I understand that obtaining a refresh token is the appropriate solution, but I'm unsure how to implement it.

I've tried logging the user out when the token expires, but I know this isn't the correct approach. Instead, I want to obtain a refresh token to automatically refresh the access token without requiring the user to sign in again.

Could someone please guide me on how to obtain and utilize a refresh token in React Native for Google Sign-In? I've searched extensively but haven't found a clear solution. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a solution finally

```
 const getTokens = async () => {
  const data = await AsyncStorage.getItem("AccessToken");

  const parts = data
    .split(".")
    .map((part) =>
      Buffer.from(
        part.replace(/-/g, "+").replace(/_/g, "/"),
        "base64"
      ).toString()
    );

  const payload = JSON.parse(parts[1]);

  console.log(Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000), "JWT payload", payload?.exp);
  Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) >= payload?.exp
    ? refreshGoogleToken()
    : console.log("your token is up to date");
};
```

I decode the token and get `exp` which gives me token expired time stamp and if token is expired then I refresh token

```
npm i buffer
```

you can use above buffer library for decode token